# $6 \equiv 6 \pmod{7}$ or $6 \equiv -1 \pmod{7}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Just a quick question: Is $6 \equiv 6 \pmod{7}$ or $6 \equiv -1 \pmod{7}$?

I'm just trying to figure out whether there was an error in the answer by Jazzachi in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893975/modular-arithmetic-congruences-with-exponents).

Thanks.

Comment: They're both true.  This follows from the raw definition of congruence.

Comment: @Randall Oh, ok. Can you please explain why?

Comment: Does $7$ divide $6-6=0$?  Yes.  Does $7$ divide $6- ^-1 = 7$?  Also yes.

Comment: $-1\mod 7$ represents the additive inverse of $1$ modulo $7$ which is $6$ as $1+6=7$ and thus $(1+6)\mod 7=0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$6 \equiv 6 \pmod{7}$$ and $$6 \equiv -1 \pmod{7}$$ are both true.

As you know the definition is $$a\equiv b\pmod {n} \iff n|(b-a)$$

For example $$35 \equiv 30 \pmod{5}$$ because $$5| 30-35$$